# media queries for iBooks

Tags: media-queries, epub, ibooks

I'm wonder is there media query for iBooks. I know there is for kindle but I cant find any for iBooks. Is media query for web ([from this website](http://www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/#iPad) will work on iBooks?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use web browser-style media queries for iBooks, although right now iBooks doesn't seem to support `orientation : landscape` or `orientation : portrait`.

it's important that you include them as links in your HTML's head rather than directly in the stylesheet:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="../Styles/iPad-styles.css" />
```

including them in the stylesheet can cause some readers to fail loading the entire stylesheet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Problem with that solution is that it will count not only on iPad but also some several android tablets. While iBooks is most advanced e-book reader software for mobile and you can use tech like MathML or some CSS3 features there is no Android app that will handle that. It is why i ask iBooks specific one.

Comment: you could detect the device using javascript `var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) !== null;` and then append the ipad stylesheet that way. i'm unsure if it's possible to disable javascript in ibooks, but if not, then this could be a solution.